# Cannot get past log in screen

Tags: login

I've tried guest session and my regular login, neither work. It accepts the password then leaves me with just the login screen's wallpaper.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Another user? The guess user?

Comment: Yes, I tried the guest user to no avail. Those are the only two users that I have on the system at present.

Comment: I can provide more information if you tell me where to look. I CAN log into a tty (ctrl+alt+f[1-6]). but startx doesn't work. nor does running "unity"

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Upgrade from kubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 abort at 65%. When I restart and try to log in show this: unable to launch "gnome-session --session=cairo-dock" X session --- "gnome-session --session=cairo-dock" not found; falling back to default session.